# What's the best script PHP to index documents, perform full text search and implement versioning?

Tags: php, indexing, versioning

I need to index a long list of documents (mostly ms office formats, pdf) and perform full text search and support versioning.

I read about lucene but it seems far to be a complete solution, does anyone know a commercial complete indexer?

Comment: Why do you consider lucene a 'far to be a complete solution'?

Answer (score 1):

For versioning use [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

For the "full text search" I found some links:

http://zez.org/article/view/83/

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/zend-search-lucene

Comment: thanks for reaply. git / mercurial are too big to be easily implementes. Lucene php api dosen't work great .

Comment: You can generate [md5 hashs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) of your files to track changes and backup the files manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Recognition Server, it's high-volume OCR, document conversion and indexing software.  http://www.abbyy.com/recognition_server/

This software creates searchable digital archives. You can download trial version and try it for free